# How To Make Background Process in Android Studio

Tags: android

hi guys thank you for answering my question,i have made an android app in android studio i want to make funtion when i close the app the function start automatically in background is there any way to do it (Sorry For My Bad English)

Comment: Hi Heryad, welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, I think your question is a bit too broad. There are a couple ways to achieve what you're trying to do in Android and there are optimal solutions and methods depending on what you're trying to do specifically. In order to better provide useful solutions to you and the community, please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use services. Here is the link for the official documentation: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Application class.

```
    public class App extends Application {

    private static App instance;
    private static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        App.context = getApplicationContext();

        startService(new Intent(this, YourBackgroundService.class));
    }
}
```

Then in BackgroundService class should be like this :

```
public class YourBackgroundService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
} <br>
```

Make sure you can declare this class in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".YourBackgroundService" />
```

If you declare like this the application will run always in background.

Comment: I downvoted because using the application to boot a service boots the service when the app is started. For the app to automatically boot in the background you have to use broadcast receivers to handle events like boot, and then start the service

Comment: Still doesn't boot the service when the device is booted, or automatically for that matter. + you have to deal with issues related to having multiple services of the same time running at once, every time the app is launched a new service is launched as well

Comment: Can you please suggest me is there any other ways for running the service even after boot also.